# Restkit mapping an array of strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Using Restkit in my iOS project and the api is getting back a generic array of strings. How do I get access to those array of strings?

This is what is returned by the api.

```
{
"servers": ["http://myserver.com", "http://myotherserver.com"]
}
```

Comment: How do you want to store the objects? Core Data? Transformable? Entities with a `serverURLString` attribute? Give a clue...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the response is an `NSDictionary`:

```
strings = [{response_object} objectForKey: @"servers"]
```

Will return an `NSArray` of the strings held in the `servers` key.

Replace {response_object} with whatever your response is. I may not be understanding your question though, it's quite vague.